# GCC 5.2 Installation/Update (OS X 10.10)

Tags: macos, gcc, go, gnu

If I want to make C++, Go, Python, PHP, etc. programs and I want to use the newest version of GCC on OS X 10.10, how should I install it or update it? Golang has its own compiler. There is Xcode, but can you somehow use it to update GCC? There is also MacPorts, which only seems to have Apple's version of GCC 4.2, which I already seem to have.

Comment: MacPorts has the port `gcc5` which is gcc-5.2.0.

Comment: MacPorts gcc5 might be my option. Do I get any benefits if I try to compile GCC myself?